# Resizing a file in Photoshop CC - no constrain proportions box?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize, creative-cloud

I'm a complete novice to Photoshop CC and I feel like I'm missing something very obvious, but I can't find the answer. I want to re-size my `1024 x 748` image to `1024 x 768`. When I look online, it simply refers me to the "Constrain Proportions" option box to accomplish this - for example, like in this pic:

[image]

However, when I go to the Image Size option, all I get is this:

[image]

I have no option to constrain proportions or not, and if I try to resize my height to 768, for instance, it tries to scale the width along with it, which I do not want and stretches the image. Am I missing something very obvious? Thanks.

Comment: I don't have CC, but I would guess the chain icon serves the same purpose as Constrain Proportions. It looks like a clickable button

Comment: @JohnB, right you are. I can't believe I overlooked that - thanks much!

Comment: Feel free to post that as an answer and mark it accepted. I hesitate to myself since it was just a guess :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The chain icon serves the same purpose as the Constrain Proportions box in other editions of PS. Credit to JohnB

Answer (score 0):

To keep an image proportional while changing only one dimension (either width or height), go to Image > Canvas Size, enlarge the canvas to the desired size. In this case, you'll have 20 pixels of space that will be blank, so you'll have to adjust the graphic accordingly.

Image Size with constrain proportions on (JohnB is right, that's the lock), will scale both width and height dimensions at the same time. That's how it keeps it proportional. For example, cutting a sheet of letter-size paper in half from top to bottom is the same as just changing the width. It's no longer the same shape. You'd have to cut it in half on both dimensions for it to remain proportional.

Answer (score -3):

yes chain is the replacement make sure it is clicked